# How to count received files in request before uploading them with multer - Express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

First of all I'm working with Node.Js, Express and Multer.
I made an API call that let the user upload some images to his profile, each user can have only 5 images or less in his profile.
So when the user upload for example 2 images, first I should make sure if he can upload this amount of images before uploading them.

Here a simplified version of the `upload` object:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'images'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, "some_random_string.jpg"),
})
const multi_upload = util.promisify(
    multer({
        storage,
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            if (file.mimetype != 'image/jpg') return cb("Invalid file type, try uploading a '.jpg'")
            else cb(null, true)
        }
    }).array('images', 4)
)
```

And here is where I do all the work:

```
router.post('/', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    // I should know here how many files are sent troughthout the request
    var result = await queryPromise("SELECT * FROM images WHERE uid = 25")
    if (/* if the user can upload more images */) {
        // send the images
    } else {
        // res.send("You can upload only ${count} more images")
    }
})
```

Comment: Unless the client manually specifies a file count in either a custom header or in a query parameter (and you're willing to trust that value), the server will not know how many attachments are present until it sees how many are encountered as it reads/parses the body.  multipart/form-data does not provide a summary of what is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with uploading the images to a temporary folder, and then analyze the user data, to know if I'll save those images or delete them